# How can deploy a new shiny app to shinyapps.io in such a way that it is found at the same link as an old app?

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps, golem

I am in a bit of a tangle.

I have shiny app A, a prototype app, which is deployed to shinyapps.io

I made a new shiny app (B) using the {golem} framework. I created a whole separate project and git repository, which was a bad idea in hind sight. Anyway, now I want to have shiny app B deployed on shinyapps.io at the same link as shiny app A was previously deployed.

So far I have combined my git repositories using [these](https://gist.github.com/msrose/2feacb303035d11d2d05) instructions. Now my shiny app A repository and local folder contain shiny app B. However, the .rpoj file is still "shiny_app_b" and shiny app name according to the description is also still "shiny_app_b". Also, I deleted all the files in the OG shiny app A, so now there is no rsconnect file.

How can I make sure it deploys under the name/link of shiny app A?

Comment: just delete the existing app on shinyapps.io and create it new with your shiny_app_b?!

Comment: @TarJae OMG you're right!!! Wow thanks, I thought I would have to rename it or something